# cast as signed and then assign to int

Tags: mysql

Have a question on mysql casting and assignment, now that I have identified the 'problem' (if it is one) I can work around, not looking for that. But after struggling to figure this out for a while I really just want to know why. It makes no sense to me and want to understand the reasoning.

```
declare wu smallint;

-- why does this work 
select cast('0' as signed) into wu;

-- but this does not 
select cast('' as signed) into wu;  

-- even though below actually returns 0
select cast('' as signed);
```

SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! We're glad you're here!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL warning code 1292 is usually a warning, not an error.

NOTE: *the following is conjecture on my part. Just my thoughts, not representative of any official MySQL documentation*

I think the difference is that the result of the expression is being *assigned* to a variable.

This

```
SELECT CAST('0' AS SIGNED)
```

works without a warning because the conversion is successful. We can assign the return to a variable, or return it as a resultset.

But this, with an "incorrect" value:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS SIGNED)
```

works (doesn't show a warning) when we're just returning a resultset. Even though the conversion isn't successful (the empty string is not a "correct" integer value), we're just returning a resultset, so it really doesn't matter, and we don't need to issue spurious warnings.

The difference we observe with `INTO local_variable`, e.g.

```
SELECT CAST('' AS SIGNED) INTO foo
```

is that the return is being *assigned* to a variable, and that's what causes the warning to be shown.

To say that a different way... running that as a bare SELECT, that's MySQL server just returning a resultset.

We can get MySQL to show a warning if we attempt to *assign* that as a value to user-defined variable. We can do this outside the context of a stored routine:

```
  CAST('' AS SIGNED) INTO @foo

  Warning Code: 1292
  Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''
```

---

I think the reasoning is that if evaluation is just going into a resultset, there's not a need to show a warning.

But if the result of the evaluation is being assigned to a variable, MySQL should show a warning.

I think part of the reasoning here is that it's likely that we are going to rely on the value assigned to the variable. (We wouldn't be assigning to a variable if we weren't.) And it's better to show a potential problem where it occurs, rather than having it show up two or twelve steps later, and having to backtrack to find out what the plastic is going on.

---

And, of course, there are several workarounds; ways to modify the expression so it doesn't throw a warning.